# cant submit a form using puppeteer in javascript

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer, webautomation, javascript-automation

i need to submit a job post form in a website.I have done Authentication part successfully but  after logging in i need to submit a job post form i dont know how to submit the form please help me with that.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 })
  await page.goto('https://corp.freshersworld.com/employers/login?src=cplogout-cphmheadr-corp-   head');


await page.type('#LoginForm_username', 'raghul@corsj.net')
await page.type('#LoginForm_password', 'raghul@990')

await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(),
  page.click('#login_button'),


]);

await page.goBack()

await page.goto('https://corp.freshersworld.com/post-job?src=DASHJPHome');
await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.screenshot({ path: 'login.png', fullPage: true });





await browser.close();
})();
```

you can find the user name and pass in the code.You can check the site for the form

[job post form[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1qbh.png)
[job post form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihDBf.png)

[this is the error i get while entering values in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgY8S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's just an example where fields are filled by their unique `id`.

```
...
...
await page.goto('https://corp.freshersworld.com/post-job?src=DASHJPHome');
await page.waitFor(1000);

await page.type('#token-input-job_position', 'My job title')
...
await page.select('#exampleFormControlSelect1', 'my-job-timing')
...
await page.waitForSelector("#hp_faceToFaceInterview");

  await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelector("#hp_faceToFaceInterview").parentElement.click();
  });


await page.screenshot({ path: 'login.png', fullPage: true });
```

Comment: That part is working fine.After logging in i need to fill and submit a job post form do you have any idea for doing that

Comment: See the example above.

Comment: Hey man its not working..it throws  No node found for selector error

Comment: Please share a Screenshot here.